# scikit learn f1 score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been using scikit learn to produce f1 scores (well I use huggingface's f1, which inturn uses scikit learn's f1 function):
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

I would have thought I could input a threshold for this since it depends on precesion and recall but I cant see any place to input this.

what is the default used?

Comment: I don't understand your question. F1 score has a formula to calculate it.  You have a precision and recall and you get F1 applying the formula. There are no thrwsholds

Answer (score 2):

The `f1_score` takes the true classes `y_true` and predicted **classes** `y_pred`. In this case, there is no use for the threshold since the predicted classes are provided.
If you have predicted **probabilities** , you can then generate the predicted **classes** using a specific threshold and then use the `f1_score` from scikit-learn.

For example, if you have the following true **classes** and predicted classes **probabilities**

```py
y_true = [1,1,0,1]
prob_class_1 = [0.44, 0.32, 0.9, 0.1]
```

Then using a threshold `0.3` you can calculate `y_pred` as following:

```py
thresh = 0.3
y_pred = [1 if i > thresh else 0 for i in prob_class_1]
```

Now you can calculate the f1-score

```py
score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred)
```